# Favorite question changes list gives ugly UUID instead of revision number

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

Found this when looking at the list of changes to a question I had favored:

[image]

Any reason why it isn't [showing revision 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/75581/revisions), a much nicer number, instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this has been fixed.